# how to convert an SQL server 2005 .mdf to SQL server CE .sdf?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

HI ,

I created a project where it can work with SQL server 2005. Now i want this project to be migrated to SQL server CE 3.5 which will run in  low config system ( XP , 500 MHZ and RAM 488) How do i convert my .mdf to .sdf  .I used third part tool lik e PrimeWork but when i am trying to load it says not compatible . any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/fd3b14c5-5474-4ad9-b373-b6385881780f/

Also, I haven't tested this, but it seems to get the job done:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlCompactCoptUtility.aspx

MAKE BACKUPS BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING! :)

Comment: The Second like i cant try b'coz its developed with VS 2008 , and the 1st I already tired but doenst work out